# UINavigationController, and TabBarController programmatically (no storyboards)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Currently, my AppDelegate file contains this code to establish the CustomTabBarController as the rootViewController:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()
```

I want my app to always have the CustomTabBarController on the bottom, but I want each tab to have a navigation controller. Here is the code I used to set up my tabBarController:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let vc1 = FirstViewController()
let vc2 = SecondViewController()
let vc3 = ThirdViewController()
viewControllers = [vc1, vc2, vc3]
}
```

Here is the code I used to set up my FirstViewController:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: VCCellId, for: indexPath) as! firstVCCell

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: do you see a navigation bar?

Comment: ok from your question as I got, you are looking for navigation controller inside tabbarcontroller. if yes then look at this link http://www.iosinsight.com/uinavigationcontroller-inside-uitabbarcontroller-with-storyboard/  if you are adding programatically    
//Initialize tabbar Controller and All Navigation Controllers are added into Tabbar Controller
self.tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSArray *arrNVControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4, nil];

self.tabbar.viewControllers = arrNVControllers;

Comment: What's the implementation of `CustomTabBarController`? You need to manually add navigation controllers around each view controller

Comment: @Alistra How would I do that? I tried subclassing the first child of my CustomTabBarController as a UINavigationController, but when I ran it there was no navigation bar.

Comment: @Md.Ib Yes I see a navigation bar

Comment: can you share your project mdibrahimhassan@gmail.com

Comment: You can't just say `navigationItem.title` and expect it to work...the viewController that it is being added to **must** be a subclass of `UINavigationController`. So follow Vacawama's answer...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When combining a `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`s, the correct way to set that up is to make the `UITabBarController` the `rootViewController`.   Each tab of your `UITabBarController` gets its own `UINavigationController`.  So, if you have 4 tabs, you will create 4 `UINavigationControllers`.

See: [Adding a Navigation Controller to a Tab Bar Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html)

---

**Update**

Building off of the code you added in your updated question, create a `UINavigationController` for each of your `vc1`, `vc2`, and `vc3`.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())
        let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondViewController())
        let vc3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ThirdViewController())

        viewControllers = [vc1, vc2, vc3]
    }

}
```

In each of your `ViewController`s, set `title` to the title you want to be displayed in the navigation bar when that tab is selected:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        title = "First"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 27)!,
             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
    }
}
```

Comment: The code on the link you have is pretty outdated, however I tried doing:    `let profileNavBar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())`, but my when I built the app, it crashed. Where FirstViewController is the first ViewController in my customtabbar.

Comment: Update your answer with the code that creates your `UICustomTabBarController` and show the code that creates the view controllers and adds them to the `UICustomTabBarController`.

Comment: Updated the code that creates UICUstomTabBarController and the FirstViewController.

Comment: That worked, but how would I changed the attributes of the nabber (like the font)? Which file would I have to change it in, and what would be the code to do that?

Comment: What is a nabber?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say navBar :/

Comment: Thanks very much, this has been helpful

Answer (score 3):

I noticed in the comments of the accepted answer that you were wondering where to change the attributes of the navigation bar. If you plan on applying the same customization to each tab you could use the following code within your CustomTabBarController:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Tab Bar Customisation
        tabBar.barTintColor = .systemPink
        tabBar.tintColor = .systemTeal
        tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .systemGray
        tabBar.isTranslucent = false

        viewControllers = [
            createTabBarItem(tabBarTitle: "Tab 1", tabBarImage: "TabBarImg1", viewController: ViewControllerOne()),
            createTabBarItem(tabBarTitle: "Tab 2", tabBarImage: "TabBarImg2", viewController: ViewControllerTwo()),
            createTabBarItem(tabBarTitle: "Tab 3", tabBarImage: "TabBarImg3", viewController: ViewControllerThree()),
            createTabBarItem(tabBarTitle: "Tab 4", tabBarImage: "TabBarImg4", viewController: ViewControllerFour())
        ]
    }

    func createTabBarItem(tabBarTitle: String, tabBarImage: String, viewController: UIViewController) -> UINavigationController {
        let navCont = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navCont.tabBarItem.title = tabBarTitle
        navCont.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: tabBarImage)

        // Nav Bar Customisation
        navCont.navigationBar.barTintColor = .systemRed
        navCont.navigationBar.tintColor = .systemBlue
        navCont.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        return navCont
    }
}
```

Personally, I like this approach, because it saves me from repeating code throughout ViewControllers and keeps the tab & nav bar code organized within your custom tab bar class.

If you don't want to use the same tab or nav bar customization throughout the app you can simply customize each one individually how you like within their respective ViewControllers class. However, if every tab is going to have different tab and/or nav attributes Vacawama's answer would most likely be the best approach!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
viewControllers = [vc1, vc2, vc3].map{UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)}
```

Comment: This gives following error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'