# Navigation bar not accessible when using SWRevealViewController with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I have set Sliding menu(Rear view controller) using SWRevealViewController with a UITabBarController (front view controller). Below is the piece of code I used:

```
RearMenuViewController *rearViewController = [[RearMenuViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

UINavigationController *navTabController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_tabBarController];


SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:navTabController];
revealController.delegate = self;
revealController.rightViewController = nil;
self.viewController = revealController;

self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

This works fine and I can toggle between the rear menu and tab bar items using swipe gesture.

**But I am not able to set the navigation title for each tab bar item nor I can add any bar button on navigation bar. I can only see blank navigation bar for every tab bar item.**

Also would like to share that I am NOT using storyboard in the project.So, I need to set the title and a bar button through code only.

Please let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: You forgot to describe (include code) how do you create the `_tabBarController`.

Comment: Another thing is that you shouldn't embed tab bar controller inside navigation view controller, but you should use it as a `frontViewController`. Then, every tab view controller should be included in the navigation view controller itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UINavigationController, and TabBarController programmatically (no storyboards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961766/uinavigationcontroller-and-tabbarcontroller-programmatically-no-storyboards)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually the post you mentioned in your comment above does not contain a SWReavealViewController. It just shows how to use navigation controller with tab bar controller. I am getting this issue when I want to add a slider menu with tab bar controller as front view controller and a rear view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access the navigation bar for each tab bar item like this:

```
UINavigationController *currentNav = (UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.parentViewController;

UINavigationItem *navItem =(UINavigationItem *) [currentNav.navigationBar.items firstObject];
navItem.title = @"Dashboard";
```

Need to write this in each item (view controller) of tab bar if we need to have different titles for each tab bar item.

Please let me know if there is a better way to achieve this.